# Which shared_ptr/object is deleted first when provided with a second?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Example:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A("First"));
    std::shared_ptr<A> b(a);
}
```

Which of these is the first to be deleted?

Comment: Did you want to know which `shared_ptr` is deleted, or when the `A` is deleted?

Comment: @MooingDuck Both. I want to know whether the object and two shared_ptr are deleted at "the same time" or if one is destroyed before the second and thus the object.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671945/when-is-object-pointed-by-stdshared-ptr-deleted

Comment: @NathanOliver That wasn't really my question. I want know if one pointer is deleted before the other. Are both pointers existend when the object is deleted?

Comment: When you leave the scope `b` is destroyed, then `a`, and since `a` is the last reference to the object that was created, that object is then destroyed.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595283/order-and-point-of-calling-destructor

Comment: Execution of a function is always sequential, so you can't destroy two objects "at the same time". (If one is a subobject, its destruction will be a step of the destruction of the enclosing object.)